# when i activate my plugin shows me this message: There has been a critical error on this website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i'm trying to build a plugin for wordpress but when i activate de plugin it shows me this error "There has been a critical error on this website", indeed the posts are generated but it seems to go infinite`
this is my code:

```
<?php 
/* 
Plugin Name: ScrapMaster 
Plugin URI: https://www.webmasterbolivia.com
Description: Web Scraping and content generator.
Version: 1.0 
Author: Marcos Selin
Author URI: https://www.webmasterbolivia.com
License: GPLv2 
*/
$new = array(
    'post_title' => 'Our new post',
    'post_content' => 'This is the content of our new post.',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
 for($i=0; $i<=5; $i=$i+1){                
     $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new );
        
    }


if( $post_id ){
    echo "Post successfully published!";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong, try again.";
}
?>`
```

Notice: Trying to get property 'feeds' of non-object in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php on line 4571

Notice: Trying to get property 'use_trailing_slashes' of non-object in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 49

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php:2623 Stack trace: #0 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php(7139): _count_posts_cache_key('post', 'readable') #1 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): _transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #2 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php(4902): do_action('transition_post...', 'publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #5 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php(4209): wp_transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #6 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-content/plugins/scrapmaster/scrapmaster.php(17): wp_insert_post(Array) #7 /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-settings.php(388): include_once('/home/abogcqvs/...') #8 /home/a in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php on line 2623

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: wordpress debugger shows me this: Notice: Trying to get property 'feeds' of non-object in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/post.php on line 4571

Notice: Trying to get property 'use_trailing_slashes' of non-object in /home/abogcqvs/cryptomania.xyz/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 49